# Alternative to GlusterFS

Tags: high-availability, cluster, glusterfs

I need to create a redunant 2-linux machines configuration so that the files on server1:/dir are in sync with the files on server2:/dir
I managed to configure GlusterFs to do this but while it works pretty fine with large files it works awfully slow when many small files are involved.
To understand better: a 150MB archive with 50K files is normally unpacked in 3-4 seconds on the regular file system but in more than 15 minutes on the GlusterFS parition!
After much reading and testing I couldn't significantly improve this.

I was wondering anyone has experience with another clustered file system that is capable of handling many small files better than glusterFS. Or if you have another suggestion on what should I try for keeping a dir on 2 servers in sync.

Comment: How far apart are these machines, and what does the network look like? You have to take latency into account, every write or meta-data operation has to wait for both the local disk and the remote network acknowledgement to complete. Any "synchronous" file-system replication technology (GlusterFS, DRBD, or whatever) will have this same requirement.

Comment: They are in the same datacenter, on a 100MB connection with 0.1ms latency.

Comment: What are you using as storage backend (SAN, iSCSI, DRBD, ...)?

Comment: @Nils - its gigabit connection, I was wrong. Still slow nevertheless. Storage: commodity SATA.

Comment: Did you try using glusterfs via nfs instead of the fuse client? It usually works a lot faster for smaller files. Sill if you need something faster maybe drbd would be better.

Comment: @Jure1873 thanks but I eventually chose to use sshfs mounted file system and works very well this way. I'll keep in mind your suggestions should I need in the future again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) does a RAID-1 over the network which might be closer to what you want.  I still have not found it to be terribly fast though.

Comment: Do you have it installed on some servers? I was curious if you could tell me how much it would take for example to unpack a kernel archive.

Comment: But if you run it in dual-primary configuration then you still need a distributed lock manager to avoid write conflicts. AFS might be a better solution to support writes at both ends.

Answer (score 3):

**DRBD** is sort of an alternative to glusterFS in that my 50K files test was completed in 40 seconds instead of 15+minutes.
My conclusion to this is that glusterFS seems fit for not-so-many large files and that DRBD works better when many small files are involved.
I know its an "apple vs pears" comparison but it it may save someone some hours of work.